# pass attribute from Java to JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript

In my Java Class I added a variable:

```
model.addAttribute("pageID", "dashboard");
```

Inside JSP I can easily call that variable with **${pageID}**. But is there a way I can call that variable directly in JavaScript? I tried all other suggestion I found over the internet, such as simply writing **var value = "${pageID}"** but that doesn't work.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: You should start by understanding that your Java class runs on the Server, while the JavaScript code runs on the Browser. Since it's two different environments, of course they cannot interact directly. This is usually done through AJAX.

Comment: If your JavaScript is in the JSP, like in the page header, it might work, done that with JSF once.

Comment: i bookmarked a link, which may be useful for you aswell http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JDK-6/PassparametertoJavaScriptthroughJavacode.htm

Comment: but what does 'doesn't work' mean? It 'should' work. View the HTML content that is generated to see what the javascript code looks like as the browser is seeing it; there must be something else you're doing wrong, or the PageID contains characters that mess up the javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried this?

```
var value = "<%= pageID %>";
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried that and console.log only displays it like a string. Well looks like it cannot be done like I imagined :) The real thing why I wanted this is because I don't have some JSP included in all pages, so I will have to create hidden input field, or something similar so I can call that value in JavaScript